# Integrating Replace Function in Access 2016 SQL Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following SQL query and want the replace all occurrences of the phrase "Vitality Blast" in the League field with "Twenty20 Cup (England)". To do this I think I need to use the Replace function but I do not know how to integrate it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

```
SELECT BallByBall.matchId, BallByBall.inningsNo, BallByBall.ballNumber, BallByBall.ballRank, BallByBall.bowler, BallByBall.batsman, BallByBall.runs, BallByBall.byes, BallByBall.legByes, BallByBall.wides, BallByBall.noBalls, BallByBall.wicket, Lineups.bowlingStyle, Matches.League, Matches.convDate, ScorecardBatting.howDismissed, (SELECT COUNT(T2.ballRank) + 1
FROM BallByBall T2
WHERE T2.matchId = BallByBall.matchId
AND T2.batsman = BallByBall.batsman
AND T2.ballRank < BallByBall.ballRank
) AS Rank
FROM ScorecardBatting RIGHT JOIN (Matches RIGHT JOIN (Lineups RIGHT JOIN BallByBall ON (Lineups.matchId = BallByBall.matchId) AND (Lineups.playerId = BallByBall.bowler)) ON Matches.matchId = BallByBall.matchId) ON (ScorecardBatting.matchId = BallByBall.matchId) AND (ScorecardBatting.batsmanId = BallByBall.batsman)
ORDER BY BallByBall.matchId, BallByBall.inningsNo, BallByBall.ballRank;
```

Comment: Do you want to update that field or to display replacement?

Comment: Hi Maciej, I'd like to update that field. Thanks

Comment: What's your input data?

Comment: Hi Maciej, it's text from a csv file. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yeah. And i'm also interested what you mean by saying: "*replace all occurrences of the phrase "Vitality Blast" in the League field with "Twenty20 Cup (England)"*". Does "Visibilit Blast" exists in `League` field  more then once per row?

Comment: Hi Maciej, no it will only ever appear once per row or not at all. It will never appear more than once per row. Thanks

Comment: OK. Does "Vitality Blast" is a part of `League` field or this field can contain other values, such as: "*Some text Vitality Blas The Other Part Of Text*". This is very important!

Comment: Hi Maciej, it will just be "Vitality Blast" with nothing else in the field. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reference to our discussion in comments, you have to use `UPDATE` statement.

```
UPDATE YourTableName SET League = 'Twenty20 Cup (England)'
WHERE League = 'Vitality Blast';
```

For further details, please see: [UPDATE statement (Microsoft Access SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/update-statement-microsoft-access-sql)

Comment: Hi Maciej, thanks. Can this be integrated into the existing code?

Comment: Not sure, what you mean... Updating data is used to change its "content". Update command can NOT be used to select data. You have to be more clear. Please, provide sample data and expected result (improve your question).